# Apply @PostFilter / @PostAuthorize for all endpoints

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security

I have been able to use @PostFilter / @PostAuthorize successfully as follows:

```
@RestController
public class MyController{
     @PostFilter("hasPermission(filterObject, 'blah')")
     public List<MyObject> getIt();
}
```

However, what I would like to do is configure the `hasPermission` (or some similar) check on all endpoints in my application. In other words, doing something like a Spring Security `Fitler` but using the domain object prior to it being marshalled in the `HttpServletResponse`. I would prefer not to use a `Filter` because of the marshalling / unmarshalling aspect especially when doing filtering (@PostFilter) as it changes the result.

The idea is that I would like this filtering behavior to be a cross-cutting security concern and therefore not have to remember to add it to each endpoint as it is added. This would also allow me to do testing of this filtering once for the application instead of for each endpoint.

Comment: Annotate one BaseController class with the `@PostFilter` and let all your controllers extends the BaseController.

Comment: That still requires a step that could be forgotten 2 years from now when a new controller is added. I am looking for some mechanism that when applied once will apply to anything that is added in a cross-cutting manner.